# @XmlSeeAlso with more than one parameter

Tags: java, groovy, jaxb, grails

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html

According to this, I should be able to make my root element have more than one class reference. However, when I try that, I get this exception:

```
[groovyc] Compiling 72 source files to C:\Users\dcole\.grails\1.3.4\projects\trunk\classes
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] C:\dev\trunk\grails-app\domain\skillsdb\Employee.groovy: 13: unexpected token: , @ line 13, column 40.
[groovyc]    @XmlSeeAlso({EmployeeDesiredSkill.class, EmployeeDesiredtool.class})
[groovyc]                                           ^
[groovyc]
[groovyc] 1 error
Compilation error: Compilation Failed
```

Is this a groovy problem, or a java problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - if you want more than one element in the annotation, you have to use groovy notation for that - changing the class enclosing to a [] instead of {} fixes the problem